# кастомизация информационного окна в Google Maps

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps-api

Я создал кастомное информационное окно из xib файла и положил в этот метод :

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {
    let infoWindow = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("InfoWindowMap", owner: self.view, options: nil)!.first! as! InfoWindowMap
    infoWindow.label.text = marker.title // эта часть работает, но берет инфу непосредстенно из маркера, но я хочу брать информацию из массива screenPlaces напрямую
    print(screenPlaces.count) =// вот тут я его проверяю, но он почему то еще не заполнен и равен 0
    return infoWindow
}
```

Мой массив `screenplaces` наполняется когда я подключаюсь к `API` вот тут:

```
 if status == "success"{
            for (_,subJson):(String, JSON) in json["data"]["services"] {
                let id = subJson["id"].intValue
                let name = subJson["name"].stringValue
                let icon = subJson["icon"].stringValue
                let adress = subJson["address"].stringValue
                let latitude = subJson["latitude"].stringValue
                let longitude = subJson["longitude"].stringValue
                self.screenPlaces.append(ScreenData(name:name, id:id,adress:adress,icon:icon, latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude))
                for i in self.screenPlaces{
                    let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double (i.latitude)!, longitude: Double( i.longitude)!)
                    let marker = GMSMarker(position: position)
                    marker.map = self.mapView
                    marker.title = (i.name)
                    marker.snippet = (i.adress)
                }
            }
```

И фишка в том, что я не могу скормить всю эту инфу в xib файл, точнее могу но малую часть наследуюясь от маркера `infoWindow.label.text = marker.title`, но это не совсем кастомизация - а ни рыба ни мясо, много информации туда не поместишь.

Если я помещаю метод `func mapView ()` сразу под `if status == "success"{}`, то не происходит ничего, даже не видно что массив пустой.Как будто система игнорирует эту часть.

Как быть?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сорямба, вопрос больше не актуален) Все работает, просто завтыкал чуток, была функция `screenPlaces.removeall()`, которую я не заметил, все работает, карты кастомизируются.